# change map type on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I tried using `mMap.changeMapType(...)` in Android studio and something weird had happened 
at first, I tried using a button to change the map type and it worked perfectly...
then o tried using an options menu that basically does the same thing and the map type just won't change. I tried using a debugger so I know it's not just stopping on "`mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);`" but it skips the "`return true;'" and goes straight to "`return false;`"
my code:`

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
           case R.id.SATELLITE:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
           case R.id.normal:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
           case R.id.hybrid:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
           case R.id.terrain:
               mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
               return true;

       }
       return false;
    }
```

Comment: send logcat error

Answer (score 1):

Fix `switch` statement as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case R.id.SATELLITE:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            break;
       case R.id.normal:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            break;
       case R.id.hybrid:
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            break;
       case R.id.terrain:
           mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            break;
       default: 
           return false;

   }
   return true;
}
```